# PHP pass a separate table value through URL

Tags: php, url, html-table, hyperlink

I have been trying to solve this for some time now so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a HTML table that loops and displays records. the last 2 columns are approve or reject hyperlinks (each run a different script for the according action. This passes the .row data for ticket number through the URL (works fine).

What I have done now is added a column before hand containing a text area which I wish to use to add comments and send the comments to next page also when  click the link. I have tried PHP and Javascript get element by id but  do not seem to be able to make it work. I am trying to pass id="feedback_comments"

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='open_inc_table'>" . "<a href='view_ticket.php?ticket_id=" . $row['ticket'] . "'>" . $row['ticket'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_start_table'>" . date_format($row['start_date'],"d/m/Y H:i:s") . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_start_table'>" . date_format($row['end_date'],"d/m/Y H:i:s") . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_priority_table'>" . $row['priority'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_priority_table'>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_priority_table'>" . $row['system'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_description_table'>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_description_table'>" . $row['resolution'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_description_table'>" . '<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="feedback_comments"></textarea>' . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_system_table'>" . "<a href='ticket_feedback_approve.php?inc_id=" . $row['ticket'] . "&feedback_comments=" . "'>" . 'Approve' . "</a>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='open_system_table'>" . "<a href='ticket_feedback_reject.php?inc_id=" . $row['ticket'] . "'>" . 'Reject' . "</a>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: when you say through a url do you mean to use $_GET['feedback_comments'] ? you can get url values with the $GET_['url_value']

Comment: Thats right, i have the GET on the next page which captures Ticket with no problem however cannot find a way to capture the comments

Comment: Ofc, you have `&feedback_comments=" . "`. It will always be empty.

Comment: left that in there as thats where im trying to have the comment data. After the . tried a few different ways to get the comments there but do not seem to be able to get it to work

Comment: You say "added a column before hand containing a text area which i wish to use to add comments", can't you use this column? Like `$row['comments']` ? Or I still didn't get the question?

Comment: you could session register the feedback comments and carry it over to the next page

Comment: Sorry to explain a little more. The ros is pulling data from the sql table and displaying in my php table. the text area column is for just free typing, its these comments i want to through through the URL, i think as its not a record in the sql table it may not be inside a row value

Comment: @unixmiah if i were to carry it through a session would it allow me to do it on different records? It is essentially an entry approval page just adding a comment when clicking approve or reject

Comment: it should; the session variable is just like the post, request and get; an array of key/val data

Answer (score 0):

Give id to anchor tag. Write a function that get value of textarea and update href attribute of anchor tag using setAttribute function. Execute function using onkeydown event and pass ticket as parameter of updateHref function.

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='open_inc_table'>" . "<a href='view_ticket.php?ticket_id=" . $row['ticket'] . "'>" . $row['ticket'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_start_table'>" . date_format($row['start_date'],"d/m/Y H:i:s") . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_start_table'>" . date_format($row['end_date'],"d/m/Y H:i:s") . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_priority_table'>" . $row['priority'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_priority_table'>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_priority_table'>" . $row['system'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_description_table'>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_description_table'>" . $row['resolution'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_description_table'>" . '<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id='feedback_comments' onkeydown='updateHref(\"" . $row['ticket'] . "\")'></textarea>' . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_system_table'>" . "<a id="approve-link">" . 'Approve' . "</a>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='open_system_table'>" . "<a href='ticket_feedback_reject.php?inc_id=" . $row['ticket'] . "'>" . 'Reject' . "</a>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
```

Here is function that will update href of approve link

```
function updateHref(ticket) {
    var comment = document.getElementById("feedback_comments").value;
    document.getElementById("approve-link").setAttribute('href', 'ticket_feedback_approve.php?inc_id=' + ticket + '&feedback_comments=' + comment);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have made a few tweeks and got it working. just a quick question, when i click approve it gets rid of the last letter in the comment. Do you know how to stop that happening?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't u understand your problem. Can you elaborate more on this?